# (LUA) Failed to install winapi

Tags: windows, lua, luarocks

im have problem with install winapi lua.
OS : Win 8.1,
Lua version: 5.1.5,
Luarocks latest.

Command line:

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\luarocks-3.9.2-windows-32>luarocks install winapi
Warning: Lua 5.4 interpreter not found at C:\Users\Didn't understanded word\Desktop\luarocks-3.
9.2-windows-32

Modules may not install with the correct configurations. You may want to configu
re the path prefix to your build of Lua 5.4 using

   luarocks config --local lua_dir <your-lua-prefix>

Installing https://luarocks.org/winapi-1.4.2-1.src.rock

Error: Could not fetch rock file: Failed creating temporary directory luarocks-r
ock-winapi-1.4.2-1: Failed setting permission exec for all

C:\Users\user\Desktop\luarocks-3.9.2-windows-32>
```

Im tried to install without luarocks winapi, but I has got C files and other didn't understanded files.